# ElasticSearch: Using an existing field in script param

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a nested object and set the field value to be a document fields value. I can create a non nested field with my logic value and I can create a nested field with a hard coded value. But I cannot get the two of these things to work together.

Here is what I have so far.
Create a nested field:

```
{
   "script": "ctx._source.displayFields = displayField",
   "params": {
     "displayField": { 
       "displayField": 11
     } 
   }  
}
```

Or I can use a script to fetch the value and sent a field like this:

```
{
  "script" : "if (ctx._source['fielda'] == 'term1') {
   ctx._source['displayField'] = ctx._source['field2']; } 
   else  if  (ctx._source['fielda'] == 'term2') {
   ctx._source['displayFields.displayPrice'] = ctx._source['fieldb'];
}
```

But if I try and put a script in the param field like either of the below I always get an error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Things I have tried and not worked:

```
{
  "script": "ctx._source.displayFields = displayField",
  "params": {
     "displayField": { 
        "displayField": "tag"
      },
      "tag" : {
         "script": "ctx._source['numberField']"
      }
    }
}
```

As well as trying to assign a script as its subfield or putting it as the value.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Richa I get a `[indices:data/write/update]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: \"tag\"];` if I try the example with the tag. And If i try to put a script inside the a sub tag It simply writes the script inside of a tag it puts the text inside instead of evaluating the statement. ex) `displayField: {
script: \"ctx._source['numberField']"
}`

Comment: Actually I just tried it again and now it just inserts the text "tag" in the field and not the script field